# the program crashes as soon i execute

Tags: c++, api, winapi, memory, shared

this program is supposed to write to shared memory using `win32` API. it is a program given as it is in text book but when i try to execute it it fails. it crashes as i click on execute

the program is supposed to write a string to shared memory

```
#include<windows.h>  
#include<stdio.h>  

int main(int argc, char *argv[])   
{   
  HANDLE hFile, hMapFile;  
  LPVOID lpMapAddress;
  //mapping of memory
  hFile=CreateFile("temp.txt",GENERIC_WRITE,0,NULL,OPEN_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);    
  hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(hFile,  NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0,0, TEXT("SharedObject"));  
  lpMapAddress = MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 0);   
  //writing into shared memory
  sprintf((char*)lpMapAddress,"shared memory writing");   


  UnmapViewOfFile(lpMapAddress);   
  CloseHandle(hFile);  
  CloseHandle(hMapFile);  
}
```

Comment: code stepping with a debugger? depends.exe? Error message?

Comment: Don't you have to map a file of > 0 bytes for memory mapped files? Although the last time I looked at memory mapped files using WINAPI was the late 1990s.

Comment: no error message is displayed . It crashes right away @ceros

Comment: ***It crashes right away*** Your debugger should help with that.

Comment: Good opportunity to [learn how to use a debugger](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: i tried to debug but it shows program recieved signal SIGSEGV,segmentation fault

Comment: Well that's what happens when you have shitty code that doesn't check for errors.

Comment: Normally you can set your debugger to break on this type of exception and then follow the stack up to your code. From your description (not a Visual Studio message) I expect you are using gdb. I can not help with that.

Comment: You didn't check for errors and reaped the usual consequences.

Comment: There are no SIGSEGV segmentation faults on Windows, and there are no error dialogs or messages that contain *"SIGSEGV"* or *"segmentation fault"*. You are either not describing the true behavior, or you are running in an environment that is not Windows (e.g. WINE).

Answer (score 4):

the reason it is crashing is because the file must be created with `GENERIC_READ` and `GENERIC_WRITE` access rights since in the `CreateFileMapping()` function your code specifies `PAGE_READWRITE` as its third argument(`flProtect`). This is from MSDN documentation of `CreateFileMapping`:

> The file must be opened with access rights that are compatible with
>   the protection flags that the flProtect parameter specifies
>
> PAGE_READWRITE=>Gives read/write access to a specific region of pages.
>   The file that hFile specifies must be created with the GENERIC_READ
>   and GENERIC_WRITE access rights.

so change

`hFile=CreateFile("temp.txt",GENERIC_WRITE,0,NULL,OPEN_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);`

to

```
hFile=CreateFile("temp.txt",GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ,0,NULL,OPEN_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
```

One more thing you can not map a file with a size of zero. Here is from MSDN documentation of `CreateFileMapping()` function:

> If this parameter(dwMaximumSizeLow) and dwMaximumSizeHigh are 0 (zero), the maximum size
>   of the file mapping object is equal to the current size of the file
>   that hFile identifies.
>
> An attempt to map a file with a length of 0 (zero) fails with an error
>   code of ERROR_FILE_INVALID. Applications should test for files with a
>   length of 0 (zero) and reject those files.
>
> If an application specifies a size for the file mapping object that is
>   larger than the size of the actual named file on disk, the file on
>   disk is increased to match the specified size of the file mapping
>   object.

so in your case since the file you are trying to map has initially a size of 0, the `CreateFileMapping()` function will fail unless you specify the size of a file mapping object in the `dwMaximumSizeLow/dwMaximumSizeHigh` parameters of `CreateFileMapping()`. You could do something like this...

```
HANDLE hFile, hMapFile;  
    LPVOID lpMapAddress;
//mapping of memory
    hFile=CreateFile(L"temp.txt",GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ,0,NULL,OPEN_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);    
    if(hFile!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        char* str="shared data to be written";//the data you want to write to the file
        int strLen=::strlen(str);//get the string length of the data you want to write
        hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(hFile,  NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0,strLen, TEXT("SharedObject")); //here you also specify the size of the mapping object to be equal to the size of data you want to write
        if (hMapFile != NULL && hMapFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
        {
            lpMapAddress = MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 0);   
            //writing into shared memory

            if(lpMapAddress!=NULL)
                sprintf((char*)lpMapAddress,"%s","shared file write");   
            else
                printf("error");//error message MapViewOfFile() failed

            UnmapViewOfFile(lpMapAddress);  
            CloseHandle(hMapFile); 
        }
        else
            printf("error");//error message CreateFileMapping() failed

        CloseHandle(hFile);  
    }
    else
        printf("error");//error message CreateFile() failed
```

Comment: i have tried that statement already but the result is still the same !!

Comment: i think there is a problem with the sprintf statement ,when i tired it without that statement the program worked properly

Comment: so i need an alternate to write into shared memory

Comment: @shashank karukonda The problem is not the sprintf function it is the fact that you are trying to create a mapping for a file with a size of 0. I have updated my answer to reflect that.